# Calculating exterior and interior orientation of any drone without camera calibration

Tags: orthophoto, orthorectification

I have a drone, how can I find the projection matrix without calibration?

Since the drone has a GPS, I know some angles and the distance between the two photos in meters. I also know the formula of the projection matrix. `P = K[R|t]`. I have an `R` Matrix. I calculated it. I know the focal length of the drone, `FOV` and the size of the images it takes. How do I calculate `K` with this information? How do I calculate `T`?

I have information about how many meters between two photos and gsd(ground sample distance). Should the values in the `T` vector be in pixels?

Comment: Meanwhile, my only aim is to make the photo in 3D.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Okey, thanks @PolyGeo

Comment: What you need is some ground truth and an algorithm called SolvePnP. Ground truth is not required if you can estimate the scene depth, using something like SfM, but that's complicated.

Regarding how to get the `K` matrix, that's very easy if you know the focal length. It's just `[fx, 0, cx; 0, fy, cy; 0, 0, 1]`, where `cx` and `cy` are the principal point coordinates, which you can set to the image centre.


Edit: formatting